# Function to convert relative paths to absolute paths?

Tags: matlab

I've spent quite some time to no avail looking for a built-in MATLAB function to convert relative file paths to absolute file paths (portably).

Is there one?

I'm looking for something preferably "built-in" (i.e. available somewhere in the MATLAB distribution, including one of its toolboxes).  Even a "package-private" function would be acceptable, as long as I can examine the source code of function.  Second best would be a third-party function, as long as it comes with a decent test suite.  I am **not** looking for a function written in response to this question.<sup>1</sup>

Absent any of the above, even a function to *test* (portably) whether a path is absolute or not would do (with the same conditions as before: either a "built-in" function or a third-party function with a test suite).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The difficulty with implementing such a function is not writing the function itself, but rather writing a sufficiently complete test suite for it (and, of course, making sure that the function passes all the tests!).</sub>

Answer (score 11):

`fullfile(pwd, relative_path)` converts a relative to a absolute path.

Comment: Sorry, but such "conversion" functions should always be idempotent; i.e. `rel2abs(rel2abs(path))` should produce the same output as `rel2abs(path)`.  Besides, I explicitly specified that I did not want functions written in response to this question (i.e. untested functions).  You answer is very much that.

Comment: @kjo `fullfile`is a built-in function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html.

Comment: @kjo there is no single build in function which does it. For a idempotent function use Java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: @Jigg: I realize that `fullfile` is a built-in function, but Daniel answer is basically the *untested* user-rolled function `function abs = rel2abs(path); abs = fullfile(pwd, relative_path); end`.  The key point is that this function is ***untested***, which I explicitly said I was not interested in.  (`fullfile` may be tested for what it's supposed to do, but the proposed application of `fullfile` to compute absolute paths is untested.)

Comment: I have not been able to get `java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()` to work; for example `java.io.File.getAbsolutePath('foo')` returns a path whose directory component is always the startup directory for the current MATLAB session, irrespective of the value of `pwd()`...  Maybe I'm not using it right...

Comment: This does not work when '.' or '..' are used in the relative path.

Comment: @LightCC  C:\foo\..\bar is a valid folder path equivalent to C:\bar, as with /home/abcd/foo/../bar is same as /home/abcd/bar on linux. Answer by Hope is more complete tho

Comment: @MilosMatovic It is a *valid* path, yes, but it is not the absolute path. At least not with how I interpret the meaning of absolute path. The question asks for a way to convert relative paths to absolute. '.' and '..' are valid path components, but make the concatenated path relative. The absolute path should have only one string that matches it - before we get into hard links/junctions, anyway..

Comment: @LightCC it is absolute, because any application running in the OS can understand it. i.e. if using some sort of IPC to send a path to a file to another app, if we send a relative path ..\foo\myfile.txt it wouldn't know where that is (unless it is running in the same folder) but if we send it C:\bar\..\foo\myfile.txt it will definitely know where it is.

Comment: @MilosMatovic We're into a terminology debate... Absolute, to me, means it always works. If any of the folders in relative references are removed from your example, the file will still exist but the path will no longer work. This "shortest, most direct" resolved path is how I take the meaning of absolute. That's what my comments apply to. In Matlab, in particular, it's comparing two paths to see if they refer to the same file that is the trick. You need the resolved paths for that.

Comment: @MilosMatovic I think the term you're looking for is *normalised*.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the method that MathWorks themselves uses:

```
    [status, info] = fileattrib(file);
    if status
        % Return the full path if fileattrib found the file.
        fullFilePath = info.Name;
    end
```

Comment: Nice one as fully from matlab and any OS .... so far I was relying on .NET call `fpath = char(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);`

Answer (score 5):

You can test if a path is absolute using

```
javaFileObj = java.io.File(pathToBeTested);
javaFileObj.isAbsolute()
```

Unlike `char(javaFileObj.getCanonicalPath())`, which indeed sometimes incorrectly returns a non-existent path relative to C:\Windows\System32, isAbsolute() seems to work properly (tested on Win7, MATLAB 2015b) Therefore the code for constructing the absolute path would look like

```
function F = rel2abs(F)
if ~java.io.File(F).isAbsolute
    F = fullfile(pwd,F);
end
```

This function has the advantage of being idempotent.

Answer (score 4):

The fullfile(pwd, relative_path) hack works well for me, but if you want something to get you the canonical form, there is no built-in (as of 2015b), but there is a well regarded downloadable script.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28249-getfullpath

Comment: Great catch! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

See if [which](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) fulfills your requirements:

```
full_path = which(relative_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's resurrect an old thread, if anyone is looking for this.

Here is a method, if you want the absolute path relative to your current working directory (or pwd).

```
% pwd: 'C:\first\branch'

dir('.\').folder % returns same as pwd, 'C:\first\branch'
dir('..\').folder % returns path one level up from pwd, 'C:\first'
dir('..\parallel_branch').folder % returns the absolute path to "parallel_branch" folder next to pwd, 'C:\first\parallel_branch'
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone landing here with slightly relaxed portability requirements (or a suitable test bench), another idea is to create a folder listing containing only a single file using the built-in `dir` function, followed by path concatenation using `fullfile`.

```
dirListing = dir(relPath);
absPath = fullfile(dirListing(1).folder, dirListing(1).name);
```

Pros:

- Idempotent, i.e. `rel2abs(rel2abs(path))` = `rel2abs(path)`
- Simplifies out any `/.` and `/..` in the relative path

Cons:

- This only works if the file exists

Tested using Matlab R2020a on Windows